# scp between 2 remote hosts using key auth

Tags: scp

I want to copy files using `scp` between two remote hosts with key-based authentication.

```
scp -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa user@host1:/tmp/myfile user@host2:/tmp/
```

The problem is that the `host2` still prompts me for a password, even though I have copied  the public key to both servers. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: What does it say in the `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth` on host2? And what do you mean by 'copied the public key to both servers' did you literary put the `id_rsa.pub` in host2's `.ssh` directory (which is wrong) or did you add it to the `authorized_keys` file in the `.ssh` directory of host2.

Comment: Let's say I swaped the hosts and the second one ask me the password. In fact I started using the same host for test.

Comment: I am confused by what you just said, could you elaborate more?

Comment: Also take a look at [this](http://superuser.com/a/686527) and see if that helps.

Comment: I mean if I try `scp -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa user@host2:/tmp/someotherfile user@host1:/tmp/` host1 ask me the password now. Other try is: `scp -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa user@host1:/tmp/file1 user@host1:/tmp/file1.copy` and I have to enter the password one time. I will try using ~/.ssh/config to specify the key for each host.

Comment: I've got it. It is not posible to do this if you don't share the same private key to all hosts because host1 creates its own session on host2 and it needs its credentials for an authentication with host2.

Answer (score 1):

Do you start from `host1` or `host2`? in which case there is a redundant `host_`, also if both user are the same, and same from starting host, `user@` is redundant.

To sum up, assuming you start from host1

- copy content of `id_rsa.pub` to the `authorized_keys` on host2
- to fetch remote file (remote to local)

  ```
  scp -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa host2:/tmp/somedistantfile /tmp
  ```
- to send (local to remote )

  ```
  scp -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa /tmp/somelocalfile host2:/tmp
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy directly between the remote machines by using:

```
ssh -A -t -v user-1@source-host scp /path/to/source/file user-2@dest-host:/path/to/dest/file
```

This will not use your local machine but will directly copy the file from `source-host` to `dest-host` which might be useful for large files.

You should first do `ssh-add .ssh/my-private-key` or use `-i .ssh/my-private-key` param in the above command.